# Insured is missing in another country

Tags: life-insurance

My father created ILIT. He is 91 years old. About 5 years ago he went missing. We think he may have gone to Romania. There is approximately $400K in it. It would be split 7 ways as I have 6 sisters. Problem is that we have no idea if he is alive or deceased. No idea how to find out. What happens to the trust? Is there a point where the trust would have to assume he is deceased and pay out? We are all just scratching our heads.

Please help

Comment: You'll need to talk to an estate attorney.

Comment: Has any attempt to locate him been made in the last 5 years?